# My SQL is super slow and I don't know what to do

Tags: mysql, sql

I am an SQL newbie but I agreed to do a facetted search in SQL because I have done it several times using other databases.

I finished in a couple of days but when I tried with a big data set it takes forever, I have been trying to optimize it for a week but it's still super slow.

These are the two tables:

record_facet (table with facets e.g {id: 1, facet_name: color, value: blue})
the table is 2m+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rec_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| facet_name | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| value      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table "record" is the actual record that u find by clicking or unclicking facets,
it has A LOT of columns (body, pictures,url) but I only use the id so I only listed id here:

record

```
+--------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                             | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

These are my indexes:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM record;
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| record |          1 | ix_record_id |            1 | id          | A         |      177054 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

SHOW INDEX FROM record_facet
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| record_facet |          1 | ix_facet_name_and_value |            1 | facet_name  | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| record_facet |          1 | ix_facet_name_and_value |            2 | value       | A         |        3527 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| record_facet |          1 | ix_rec_id               |            1 | rec_id      | A         |      423773 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

and these are the two queries I do:

Query to get facets:
(this is the slow one)

```
SELECT rf.facet_name, rf.value, count(*) AS c
            FROM record_facet rf
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT r.id 

            FROM record as r
             LEFT JOIN record_facet f ON r.id = f.rec_id 
            WHERE  ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'PartNum' )  OR  ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'Price' ) 
         GROUP BY r.id HAVING COUNT(r.id) = 2
            ) as rs on rs.id = rf.rec_id
            GROUP BY rf.facet_name, rf.value 
            LIMIT 10000
```

ANd this is the query to get the results:
(not so slow)

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS r.* 
            FROM record as r
             LEFT JOIN record_facet f ON r.id = f.rec_id 
            WHERE  ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'PartNum' )  OR  ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'Price' ) 
         GROUP BY r.id HAVING COUNT(r.id) = 2 LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

here are the explains:

```
SLOW QUERY:
+------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                     | key                     | key_len | ref                                    | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | rf         | index | ix_rec_id                         | ix_facet_name_and_value | 309     | NULL                                   | 296638 |                                                                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | key0                              | key0                    | 9       | sqlse_test_crescentbconflate.rf.rec_id |     10 | Using where                                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED     | f          | ref   | ix_facet_name_and_value,ix_rec_id | ix_facet_name_and_value | 52      | const                                  | 833738 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DERIVED     | r          | ref   | ix_record_id                      | ix_record_id            | 9       | sqlse_test_crescentbconflate.f.rec_id  |      1 | Using where; Using index                                            |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+


THE OTHER QUERY: 

+------+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                     | key          | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | r     | index | ix_record_id                      | ix_record_id | 9       | NULL                              |    5 | Using where                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref   | ix_facet_name_and_value,ix_rec_id | ix_rec_id    | 4       | sqlse_test_crescentbconflate.r.id |    7 | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

I'm only concerned about the slow query.
Any help is appreciated thanks so much!

Comment: `Using temporary; Using filesort ` indicates that a temporary table is created, and also sorting is done on at least one column that isn't indexed.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' everything, I tried using "IN" instead of join I tried different index combinations and so on

Comment: I can imagine a situation in which an attribute might be 'price', but a value??? How does that work?

Comment: @Strawberry: Maybe an EAV design?

Comment: @mike-sherrill-cat-recall certainly - but that doesn't really fit with that whole 'colour:blue' thing mentioned in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, a bit more readable from my perspective:

```
SELECT rf.facet_name, rf.value, count(*) AS c
FROM record_facet rf INNER JOIN
     (SELECT r.id 
      FROM record r LEFT JOIN
           record_facet f
           ON rf.id = f.rec_id 
      WHERE ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'PartNum' )  OR 
            ( f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value = 'Price' ) 
      GROUP BY r.id
      HAVING COUNT(r.id) = 2
     ) rs 
     ON rs.id = rf.rec_id
GROUP BY rf.facet_name, rf.value
LIMIT 10000;
```

This can be simplified by removing the `join` in the subquery.  It doesn't seem necessary:

```
SELECT rf.facet_name, rf.value, count(*) AS c
FROM record_facet rf INNER JOIN
     (SELECT f.rec_id
      FROM record_facet f
      WHERE f.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f.value  IN ('PartNum', 'Price' ) 
      GROUP BY f.rec_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     ) rs 
     ON rs.rec_id = rf.rec_id
GROUP BY rf.facet_name, rf.value
LIMIT 10000;
```

This version can benefit from an index on `record_facet(facet_name, value)` as well as `record_facet(rec_id, facet_name, value)`.

Next, this, in turn, seems to be asking for all "facets" that have both values.  So, I'd be inclined to write this as:

```
SELECT rf.facet_name, rf.value, count(*) AS c
FROM record_facet rf 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM record_facet f2
              WHERE f2.rec_id = rf.rec_id AND
                    f2.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f2.value = 'PartNum'
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM record_facet f2
              WHERE f2.rec_id = rf.rec_id AND
                    f2.facet_name = 'HasProp' AND f2.value = 'Price'
             )
GROUP BY rf.facet_name, rf.value
LIMIT 10000;
```

For this, you want a composite index on `record_facet(rec_id, facet_name, value)`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will go do some benchmkars.
I created the new indexes, 
does it matter if I have all these indexes at the same time: 

record_facet(facet_name, value)
record_facet(rec_id)
record_facet(rec_id,facet_name, value)


Also, the last example did not work unless I change " f. " to rf. , is that what you meant?

Comment: @user2348668 . . . That was a typo.  You are correct about the `rf`.

Comment: @user2348668: with index on `record_facet(recid,facet_name,value)`, the index on `record_facet(recid)` is redundant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I ended using the second solution, but I was wondering when would index record_facet(rec_id, facet_name, value) be useful if I'm only searchin by name and value

Comment: @user2348668 . . . The correlated subquery is using `rec_id`.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a guarantee that the **`(rec_id,facet_name,value)`** tuple is unique in the **`record_facet`** table, then a query `JOIN` operations would return the same result as the `EXISTS (correlated subquery)` example query from Gordon's answer.

```
  SELECT rf.facet_name   AS `facet_name`
       , rf.value        AS `value`
       , COUNT(*)        AS `c`
    FROM record_facet rf
    JOIN record_facet pr
      ON pr.rec_id = rf.rec_id
     AND pr.facet_name = 'HasProp'
     AND pr.value      = 'Price'
    JOIN record_facet pn
      ON pn.rec_id = rf.rec_id
     AND pn.facet_name = 'HasProp'
     AND pn.value      = 'PartNum'
   GROUP
      BY rf.facet_name
       , rf.value
   LIMIT 10000
```

Appropriate covering indexes will be needed for optimal performance.

```
... UNIQUE INDEX ... ON facet_record (rec_id, value, facet_name)
... UNIQUE INDEX ... ON facet_record (facet_name, value, rec_id)
```

---

**tl;dr**

It looks like we are assuming that you are using InnoDB, and that the InnoDB memory structures (like the buffer pool) are appropriately sized, and that MySQL isn't bogged down thrashing the disks.)

Echoing Gordon's comments... and following up a bit...

It looks like the desired return from the query is the set of *all* `facet_name` and `value` associated with every `record` that has related to it two particular `record_facet` rows... `HasProp` `PartNum` and `Price`.

The fact that the original query is including a condition **`COUNT(r.id) = 2`** makes it look like we only want to return rows associated with `records` that have *both* a `PartNum` and a `Price`.

And it seems like that condition in the query depends on the *uniqueness* of  `(rec_id, 'HasProp','PartNum')`. That is, if we had two (or more) `PartNum` rows for a given `rec_id`, and there was no associated `Price` row, that `record` would be included by the query, even though it didn't have a `Price`.

And if the `record` had two `PartNum` rows and a `Price` row, the row would be excluded (because `COUNT(r.id)` would return a value of 3). All of that makes it look like the tuples with `Price` and `PartNum` (at least) are expected to be unique.

If the original query specified **`COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) = 2`**, that would be a clue to us that `(rec_id,'HasProp','PartNum')` might not be unique.

If the intent is to return a set of `(facet_name,value)` including values other than `('HasProp','PartNum') and`('HasProp','Price')`... (which is what it looks like the original query is doing...

If that's the result that is needed...

If we have a guarantee that the **`(rec_id,facet_name,value)`** tuple is unique in the **`record_facet`** table, then a query `JOIN` operations would return the same result as the `EXISTS (correlated subquery)` example query in Gordon's answer.

```
  SELECT rf.facet_name   AS `facet_name`
       , rf.value        AS `value`
       , COUNT(*)        AS `c`
    FROM record_facet rf
    JOIN record_facet pr
      ON pr.rec_id = rf.rec_id
     AND pr.facet_name = 'HasProp'
     AND pr.value      = 'Price'
    JOIN record_facet pn
      ON pn.rec_id = rf.rec_id
     AND pn.facet_name = 'HasProp'
     AND pn.value      = 'PartNum'
   GROUP
      BY rf.facet_name
       , rf.value
   LIMIT 10000
```

One big difference between this query and Gordon's `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` form... the `COUNT(*)` will potentially return a different value if the `(rec_id,facet_name,value)` tuple is not unique. That is, this query depends on *uniqueness* and `EXISTS` form does not.

Without a guaranteed of uniqueness, we might be able to get an equivalent result by using `COUNT(DISTINCT rf.rec_id)` in place of `COUNT(*). But we also might not see any difference in performance.)

The query would likely make effective use of both of these covering indexes:

```
 ... UNIQUE INDEX ... ON facet_record (rec_id, value, facet_name)
 ... UNIQUE INDEX ... ON facet_record (facet_name, value, rec_id)
```

This query might have a different execution plan than the `EXISTS` form. And we might see a difference in performance.

---

Also, I suspect that the cardinality of `value` is much higher than `facet_name`.

So if there isn't a requirement to return the rows in `facet_name` order (i.e. we aren't relying on the `ORDER BY` implied by the `GROUP BY`) we could add `ORDER BY NULL`, or swap the order of the columns `GROUP BY rf.value, rf.facet_name`, we might get better performance with an index with `value` a the leading column.

```
  ... UNIQUE INDEX ... ON facet_record (value, facet_name, rec_id)
```

But if the number of rows returned exceeds the `LIMIT`, then we would (very likely) be getting a different set of rows, due to the difference in ordering.